# Is it bad to store JSON on disk?

Tags: javascript, xml, json

Mostly I have just used XML files to store config info and to provide elementary data persistence. Now I am building a website where I need to store some XML type data. However I am already using JSON extensively throughout the whole thing. Is it bad to store JSON directly instead of XML, or should I store the XML and introduce an XML parser.

Comment: Why must you store JSON in XML opposed to storing it in its own file?  XML is not a data storage device, so you may need to evaluate your reasons for why you use XML and JSON.

Comment: YOu didn't understand the question.

Comment: @DevDevDev - may the inquiring minds know why none of these answers tickled your fancy enough to accept one? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not bad at all. Although there are more XML editors, so if you're going to need to manually edit the files, XML may be better.

Comment: I'd argue it's just as easy to read JSON these days with javascript syntax highlighting and code folding in most editors.

Answer (score 8):

Differences between using XML and JSON are:

- A lot easier to find an editor supporting nice way to edit XML. I'm aware of no editors that do this for JSON, but there might be some, I hope :)
- Extreme portability/interoperability - not *everything* can read JSON natively whereas pretty much any language/framework these days has XML libraries.
- JSON takes up less space
- JSON may be faster to process, ESPECIALLY in a JavaScript app where it's native data.
- JSON is more human readable for programmers (this is subjective but everyone I know agrees so).

Now, please notice the common thread: **any of the benefits of using pure XML listed above are 100% lost immediately as soon as you store JSON as XML payload**.

Therefore, the gudelines are as follows:

- If wide interoperability is an issue and you talk to something that can't read JSON (like a DB that can read XML natively), use XML.
- Otherwise, I'd recommend using JSON
- NEVER EVER use JSON as XML payload unless you must use XML as a transport container due to existing protocol needs AND the cost of encoding and decoding JSON to/from XML is somehow prohibitively high as compared to network/storage lossage due to double encoding (I have a major trouble imagining a plausible scenario like this, but who knows...)

**UPDATED**: Removed Unicode bullets as per info in comments

Comment: It's not necessarily true that JSON is faster to parse in JavaScript: if you use Crockford's json2.js rather than eval then I've observed it being slower than parsing equivalent XML in IE. I have no benchmarks to hand though, sorry.

Comment: Which library do you use to parse the XML (out of sheer curiosity, in case I need to do fast XML parsing later in life?)

Comment: None, just the browser's built-in XML parsing stuff. DOMParser in non-IE browsers and the Microsoft.XMLDOM ActiveX object in IE.

Comment: What language has no JSON library?

Comment: JSON is faster to process because it is simpler than XML.

Comment: @J.F. - For example, ADA has XML support but not JSON based on my cursory Googling. That affects many projects doing government-oriented (especially DoD) work.

Comment: @J.F. Upvoted Unicode comment and edited the asnwer. Thanks for the info!

Comment: my view is that JSON is not as readable as XML... its delimiters(, ; [ and ]) can become confusing at times

Answer (score 3):

It's just data, like XML.  There's nothing about it that would preclude saving it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Define "bad". They're both just plain-text formats. Knock yourself out.

Comment: I think he mean if there are obvious downsides or violations of best practices in doing that :)

Answer (score 2):

If your storing the data as a cache (meaning it was in one format and you had to process it programatically to "make" it JSON. Then I say no problem. As long as the `consumer` of your JSON reads native JSON then it's standard practice to save cache data to disk or memory.

However if you're storing a configuration file in JSON which needs human interaction to "process" then I may reconsider. Using JSON for simple Key:Value pairs is cool, but anything beyond that, the format may be too compact (meaning nested { and [ brackets can be hard to decipher).

Answer (score 1):

one potential issue with JSON, when there is deep nesting, is readability, 
you may actually see ]]]}], making debugging difficult